# Need to write a string with exponent to file

Tags: python, ascii

I need to write feet cubed (ft**3) to a file that will be read by another program, where the 3 is a superscript. When I cut and paste the text I need from an example input file (like this: ft³) and try to save the script it says:

"Encoding file [filename] using "ascii" encoding will result in information loss. Do you want to continue?"

The command I am using is:

```
f.write('Units ft³\n')
```

What kind of information will I be losing? How do I write 'ft³' (I assume in ascii format?) from my script to my input file? I'm not even sure where to begin so any information is appreciated.

I am using PyScripter IDE if that makes any difference.

Comment: Ascii does not support the character '³'. Can't you use a more modern encoding, like utf8?

Answer (score 1):

Joran's option works for my text editors, but unfortunately comes across as a replacement character (�) when I try to open the input file with the program. The program uses Micr$oft [File.ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.90).aspx) method, so it should be able to read the text if it is encoded in utf8, right?

```
file.write('units ft'+'\xb3'+'/day\n'.encode('utf8'))
```

Unfortunately, I am still getting the replacement character when I try to open the file in the program. The input file looks fine in a text editor and when I cut and paste the line from the text editor:

```
Units ft³/day
```

To answer Mephy's question: the error regarding the ASCII character came when I copied the ft³/day string from an existing input file and simply pasted it into my python script, hoping python would write it the same way the program reads it... but that didn't work either. When I do a file compare in UltraEdit the lines are reported as being the same, yet the program will read the one it produced but not the one my python script produced. If I change the units to something without an exponent (i.e. acre-feet) it works fine.

(For clarification, I am the user who posted the original. However, I have lost my password for that account and cannot merge the two accounts with out it.)

Comment: Contact the site through the Contact Us link at the bottom of every page to have your accounts merged. Then you can edit this new information into your question. This is not what the **Your Answer** box is for.

Comment: I tried that. I clicked the link sent to each email address within the specified 48 hours. The only followup email I received was that my accounts could not be merged because I did not click the links. So I gave up.

I would have commented rather than posted an "answer"t, but I don't have enough reputation points to comment. Seems odd that I can post answers and comment on my own answers, but I can't comment on other people's answers, donchathink? As such, there was no other option to interact with the community.

Comment: I'm sorry to hear you are having problems with this. AFAIK it should not have been troublesome. Please, do post on [meta]; that will attract the attention of people who know how to handle your issues. It is the proper place to interact with the community.

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('some_file.txt','wb'): # save non-ascii bytes (superscript 3 might even work with just 'w')
    f.write('Units ft\xb3\n') #\xb3 is the superscript 3 in utf8 encoding
```

you can do this which will be recognized by *most* test editors

Answer (score 0):

Okay, problem solved. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction Joran. Although I'm not sure why I have to `.encode('utf8')` the string, since as you state `\xb3` is already in utf8. But I tried and tried and it won't work without the `.encode('utf8')`.

In the second post I was encoding the wrong part of the string. Either of these works:

```
f.write('Units ft'+u'\xb3'.encode('utf8')+'/day\n')
```

or `encode('utf8')` the whole line:

```
f.write(('Units ft'+u'\xb3'+'/day\n').encode('utf8'))
```

Is one preferred over the other?